# SVG - linearGradient. Transformation ratio matrix (4x4)

Tags: svg, linear-gradients

I would like to write a function that described the coefficients of the transformation matrix of `linearGradient` using a transformation matrix of dimension 4x4. Please help to fill in this matrix with the coefficients necessary to apply this matrix to some object.

For example, we have a description of the gradient:

```
<linearGradient
   id="linearGradient2286"
   x1="75.927002"
   x2="136.64999"
   y1="32.581001"
   y2="127.08"
   gradientTransform="matrix(0.20149,0,0,0.20149,-413.35,-155.75)"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop
     stop-color="#6262f1"
     offset="0"
     id="stop2" />
  <stop
     stop-color="#1d1d34"
     offset="1"
     id="stop4" />
</linearGradient>
```

I want to fill in the transformation matrix of the view:

```
Matrix4 m1 = (
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: SVG is a 2D technology only.

Comment: It is true. I need to transfer 2D SVG data to a transformation matrix of a certain type - 4x4. That is, as a result, I need to get a 4x4 matrix. How this can be done is still not clear to me.

Comment: The mathematical description of `matrix()` is part of the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#mathematical-description)

Comment: In Flutter I have to provide matrix transformation 4x4 which describe vector 2x2 transformed with matrix 4x4. I wander how I can transform 2x2 line (which described by vector 2x2 + matrix data) to 4x4 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the layout of your matrix, I would expect it to be either:

```
0.20149, 0,       0, 0,
0,       0.20149, 0, 0,
0,       0,       1, 0,
-413.35, -155.75, 0, 1
```

or the transposed version

```
0.20149, 0,       0, -413.35,
0,       0.20149, 0, -155.75
0,       0,       1, 0,
0,       0,       0, 1
```

Comment: Ok. I see. So how merge that matrix with vector data (two dots - it is matrix 2x2)?

Comment: We are getting into the subject of matrix multiplication now. To multiply a set of coordinates with a matrix, you have to effectively convert your coordinates into a matrix. The number of columns in one matrix has to match the number of rows in the other. Eg. In the case of your 4x4 matrix, it would have to be a 1x4 or 4x1 matrix. So the point (x,y) would become [x, y, 0, 1].  A full explanation is beyond the scope of a comment. So I recommend reading up on matrix multiplication and vector maths. Here's a good place to start: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/scalar-vector-matrix.html